# How to prevent ALL of Jackson auto-config in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson2

## Context

I have a situation where I do not control the `main` of the application nor the libraries on the class path. I am extending (via a plug-in API) an existing Swing application. The goal of my project is to make the information inside of that legacy application available through a HTTP API to then interface it via a web application.

## Technical situation

The application in question has already *Jackson* in the class path in version `2.7`. I am trying to use *Spring Boot* version `2`, which is built against *Jackson* `2.8`. When I start the server, *Spring* is unable to initialise because it is trying to configure *Jackson* stuff, using classes and methods that did not exist in `2.7`.

What I would like to do is **prevent** *Spring* from automatically configuring anything *Jackson*-related and let me provide my own content negotiator.

I already tried

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = arrayOf(JacksonAutoConfiguration::class)
)
```

but it does not work.

Digging into *Spring* code, I see places where it is hard-coded inside of `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` that is *Jackson* is on the class path, it should create new objects (that cause the exception in question), despite the fact I am excluding the *Jackson* configuration in my *Spring Boot* application.

```
private static final boolean jackson2Present =
        ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class.getClassLoader()) &&
                ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator", AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class.getClassLoader());
```

and then later:

```
    if (jackson2Present) {
        addPartConverter(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
```

## Project as it is now

Here is a link to GitHub, to the right branch.

https://github.com/Adeynack/finances/tree/spring--jackson-init-bypass/backend

The project in this state causes the error. Run `./gradlew server-standalone:run`.

## Complete error log

The errors I get are the following:

```
2017-11-30 17:15:54,475 | ERROR | main                                 | o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication | Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
    at com.github.adeynack.finances.backend.serverStandalone.FinancesServerStandalone.main(FinancesServerStandalone.kt:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$83/517355658.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext$$Lambda$126/1009916891.onStartup(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:575)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.java:29)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.httpPutFormContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:161)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9ae12ce.CGLIB$httpPutFormContentFilter$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9ae12ce$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$60a40e61.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9ae12ce.httpPutFormContentFilter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:155)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

## Gradle file

I was able to recreate the conditions of this situation with this Gradle build file.

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
        spring_boot_version = '2.0.0.M5'
        junit_version = '5.0.1'
        jackson_version = '2.7.9' // has to match Moneydance included Jackson version
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' } // remove when using a stable version of Spring Boot 2.x
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
    }
}

subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
//    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' // causes problems with Spring Boot 2. Unable to compile sub-projects.
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }
    }

    dependencies {

        //
        // PRODUCTION
        //

        // Kotlin and language extensions
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

        // Spring
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$spring_boot_version") {
            // Totally excluding Jackson (version conflict between version included in Moneydance and the one used in SpringBoot
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype'
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module'
        }

        compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jackson_version"

        //
        // TEST
        //

        // JUnit
        testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version")
        testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version")

    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    junitPlatform {
        platformVersion '1.0.0'
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of excluding `Jackson` auto-configs, try to add a newer version of `Jackson` library on the classpath

Comment: What build tool are you using and can you include the relevant config file (e.g. `pom.xml`)?

Comment: I think specifying the required dependency in pom.xml will override the Spring Boot's default jackson dependency.

Comment: @er-han : There is a newer version of _Jackson_ in the fat-JAR of my plugin, which ends up in the classpath. But apparently, since those classes are already on the classpath, the "2nd ones to be loaded" are not used.

Comment: @AmitKBist : I added the _Gradle_ build file at the end of my original post.

Comment: @RobertFarley : I added the _Gradle_ build file at the end of my original post.

Comment: I am not gradle expert, but can you do by trying including the jackson dependency with the version which you are interested in, instead of excluding those dependencies.

Comment: I also added a link to the project, pointing at the right branch.

Answer (score 2):

The not-found class which causes the exception is `InvalidDefinitionException`

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException

I found out that `InvalidDefinitionException` class exists in Jackson since 2.9 as you can see here: [InvalidDefinitionException](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException.java)

So I changed the `jackson_version` value to `2.9.2` ([latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-kotlin)) in `build.gradle` and tried to run the project as you described and the project started to run with no exception.

Now to exclude `Jackson` you can still use this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = arrayOf(JacksonAutoConfiguration::class)
)
```

Comment: As stated in the initial question: I have _no control_ over the version of Jackson that is used at runtime. It is `2.7` because it is already on the classpath.

Comment: My goal here is to tell _Spring_ not to automatically configure _Jackson_ content negotiators and let me provide one manually.

Comment: That will work well for the stand-alone server, which is just for the test. The REAL end product runs inside of _Moneydance_ which is the application in which I do not control nor the main nor the class path (where _Jackson_ 2.7 is already present).